# click event handler not working after class changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If the user clicks on one of the `ul`s then the color and the class should be changing. I solved it with this code, but I noticed that the event handlers are not working anymore after I change the class.

The `ul`s should change their color on each click.

```js
$("ul.AAA").click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  $(this).removeClass("AAA");
  $(this).addClass("BBB");
})

$("ul.BBB").click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  $(this).removeClass("BBB");
  $(this).addClass("AAA");
})
```

```css
div#start {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.AAA {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.BBB {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="AAA">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="BBB">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

I also tried it with `on`:

```js
$("ul.AAA").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  $(this).removeClass("AAA");
  $(this).addClass("BBB");
})

$("ul.BBB").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  $(this).removeClass("BBB");
  $(this).addClass("AAA");
})
```

```css
div#start {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.AAA {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.BBB {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="AAA">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="BBB">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you need to delegate the event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're changing classes dynamically you need to use `on()`, however you need to use the delegated version of it. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul.AAA", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  $(this).toggleClass("AAA BBB");
})

$(document).on("click", "ul.BBB", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  $(this).toggleClass("AAA BBB");
})
```

```css
div#start {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.AAA {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.BBB {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="AAA">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="BBB">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also note the use of `toggleClass()` over `addClass()` and then `removeClass()`

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) article to further understand. I btw comepletely agree with this answer. (the problem: with the way you handle the events at the moment is that jQuery won recognize the elements added in the future, removing and adding the classes will result in the event not happening (since the initial "button¨ doesn't excist anymore))

Comment: @AmareshChinnakotla I have already rejected your edit twice. If you want to leave a comment please feel free, but I'd prefer it if you did not edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.AAA", function() {
    //Rest of your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

A good read [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("click","ul.AAA",function() {//delegate the event to document
    //$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).removeClass("AAA");
    $(this).addClass("BBB");
  }
)

$(document).on("click","ul.BBB",function() {//delegate the event to document
    //$(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    $(this).removeClass("BBB");
    $(this).addClass("AAA");
  }
)
```

```css
div#start {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.AAA {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.BBB {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="AAA">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="BBB">
  <li>
    <p>LIST 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```